# MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification not working when 'DONE' is pressed on movie player

Tags: xcode

I've been trying to figure this out and tried to follow any advice out there but I can't seem to get 'MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification' to work after the user presses 'Done' on the movie player.

```
- (void)myMovieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification*)aNotification {
     MPMoviePlayerController* theMovie=[aNotification object];
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:theMovie];
     [theMovie pause];
     [theMovie stop]; 
     [theMovie autorelease]; 
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait animated:YES];
 }

- (void)myMovieViewFinishedCallback:(NSNotification*)aNotification {
     MPMoviePlayerViewController* theMovieView=[aNotification object];
     [self dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated];
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:theMovieView];
     [theMovieView pause];
     [theMovieView stop];
     [theMovieView autorelease];
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait animated:YES];
 }

- (IBAction)safetyVideo:(id)sender {
     NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Ball_Crunch" ofType:@"m4v"];

     if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] doubleValue] >= 3.2) {
         MPMoviePlayerViewController*tmpMoviePlayViewController=[[[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]] retain];
         if (tmpMoviePlayViewController) {
             [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:tmpMoviePlayViewController]; 
             tmpMoviePlayViewController.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
             [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(myMovieViewFinishedCallback:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:tmpMoviePlayViewController];

             [tmpMoviePlayViewController.moviePlayer play];
         }

     }else{
         MPMoviePlayerController* theMovie = [[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]] retain];
         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(myMovieFinishedCallback:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:theMovie];

         [theMovie play];
     }
}
```

The movie plays fine and disappears when 'Done' is pressed but the callbacks are never called.  Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Anybody out there?  * crickets *

Answer (score 8):

Same problem here. Figured out, when I send `nil` as object (instead of the `MoviePlayerController`) the callback is triggered...

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909138/mpmovieplayerplaybackdidfinishnotification-not-being-called/5909309#5909309) saved me.  If the video goes full screen, capture `MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification` instead of `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification`.  I capture both below just in case I change my mind later.

```
- (void)videoButtonClick:(id)sender {
    MPMoviePlayerController* moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:theVideoURL];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification object:moviePlayerController];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:moviePlayerController];
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
    moviePlayerController.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    moviePlayerController.initialPlaybackTime = 0;
    moviePlayerController.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
    moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
    [moviePlayerController play];
}

- (void)moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    MPMoviePlayerController* moviePlayerController = notification.object;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:moviePlayerController];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification object:moviePlayerController];
    moviePlayerController.initialPlaybackTime = -1;
    [moviePlayerController stop];
    [moviePlayerController release];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure for

```
    moviePlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeNone;
```

Comment: if I pass `MPMovieRepeatModeOne` then how can I receive this notification??

Comment: I want to play again and again video and receive event when video starts or ends playing....

Answer (score 0):

i realize this is a old question, but none of the above solved my problems.
If you end up trying everything like i did, make sure your parent view controller aint using the same method for notification. I was sending the notification to the wrong place.

Change the selector name for something less usual and try again.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(MyMovieClosedThisTimeForReal:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can observe to `UIWindowDidBecomeVisibleNotification` and `UIWindowDidBecomeHiddenNotification` as stated in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25952797/569497). This works even in iOS 8.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(windowVisible:)
                                             name:UIWindowDidBecomeVisibleNotification
                                           object:self.view.window];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(windowHidden:)
                                             name:UIWindowDidBecomeHiddenNotification
                                           object:self.view.window];

- (void)windowVisible:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"-windowVisible");
}

- (void)windowHidden:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"-windowHidden");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem and no other solution worked for me.
The problem is that when adding the observer, the object parameter should be tmpMoviePlayViewController.moviePlayer and not just moviePlayer.

The tmpMoviePlayViewController.moviePlayer (class MPMoviePlayerController) is the one sending the notification, not the tmpMoviePlayViewController (class MPMoviePlayerViewController).

So change this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(myMovieViewFinishedCallback:)
     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:tmpMoviePlayViewController];
```

to this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(myMovieViewFinishedCallback:) 
     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:tmpMoviePlayViewController.moviePlayer];
```